# What is the difference between the various shell profiles?

Tags: bash, shell, profile

What's the difference between ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_logout, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/ssh/ssh_config and sshd_config, when are they loaded and what are their purposes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The man page for bash says there are the following initialization files for bash shells:

```
/etc/profile
      The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
/etc/bash.bashrc
      The systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file
/etc/bash.bash.logout
      The systemwide login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
~/.bash_profile
      The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
~/.bashrc
      The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
~/.bash_logout
      The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when a login shell exits
~/.inputrc
      Individual readline initialization file
```

Apparently there seem to be different configuration files for the different shells (bash, zsh, csh, and others). There seem to be as many shells as different linux and unix versions: csh, ksh, bash, zsh, ... Bash has a `.bashrc`, Zsh has a `.zshrc`, etc. One can also distinguish between login shells and non-login shells and between system-wide defaults and user-specific defaults.

It makes sense to distinguish between **login** and **non-login** shells, because some commands should be processed only at login, while other commands should run everytime you open a new terminal window. That is the difference between [.bash_profile and .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html). For bash the `.bashrc` is reloaded every time you start a new copy of bash, i.e. when you start a new bash but do not login. The `.bash_profile` or `.profile` is loaded only when you login. The abbtreviation rc in bashrc stands for "run commands" or "run control" and is a convention adopted from older Unix systems.

system-wide defaults for..

- `/etc/profile` ..login shells, for interactive shells with login
- `/etc/bashrc`  ..non-login Bash shells

user-specific defaults in home directory ~ for..

- `~/.profile`  ..login shells, called after login
- `~/.bashrc`   ..non-login shells, if already logged in
- `~/.bash_profile` ..login shells, called after login (lower priority)

user-specific defaults in home directory for login and logout

- `~/.bash_login` ..login shells (called upon login)
- `~/.bash_logout` ..login shells (called upon logout)

The following links were helpful: [.bashrc vs .bashprofile](http://lcorg.blogspot.com/2010/01/bashrc-vs-bashprofile.html) and [.bash_profile vs .bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), the [bash manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (man bash), and [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.)](http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/).

Answer (score 2):

I happen to be curious about these files and did some experiment myself. It turns out to be a little different than what is in the documents.

I know the differences between interactive and non-interactive or login and non-login.

I tried on two computers, my macbook pro with OS 10.9 and a server with ubuntu server 13.10. I add the following command into the /etc/profile:

```
echo "Loading /etc/profile"
```

And similar commands into /etc/bash.bashrc, /etc/bashrc, /etc/bash.bashrc, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_login and make sure that these files do not source each other inside themselves.

(OS 10.9, GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13))
On the mac, with interactive login bash, I have:

```
Loading /etc/profile
Loading ~/.bash_profile
```

Which means that the files loaded directly are only /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile.

with interactive non-login bash, I have:

```
Loading ~/.bashrc
```

which means that the file loaded directly is ~/.bashrc.

(ubuntu server 13.10 GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))
On the ubuntu, with interactive login bash, I have:

```
Loading /etc/profile
Loading ~/.bash_profile
```

Which means that the files loaded directly are only /etc/profile and ~/.bash_profile.

with interactive non-login bash, I have:

```
Loading /etc/bash.bashrc
Loading ~/.bashrc
```

which means that the files loaded directly are /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

I do not know why~