# Sourcing licenses automatically

Tags: linux

In linux I am using some tools which have licenses. Every time invoke a shell, I am sourcing the licenses manually. Where should I place the command so that when I invoke a shell, it gets the licenses sourced automatically. Lets say the command looks like this:

source tool_license

Comment: Add the line to your /etc/profile? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372751/what-is-the-difference-between-the-various-shell-profiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding this to your .bash_profile in your user home, if the license can be added in as an env variable?

```
export tool_license=/home/user/license
```

or you can try this https://superuser.com/questions/591321/execute-a-command-every-time-terminal-is-open.